# SSIS prefilter records before extraction

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, oracle11g, data-migration

I have to migrate records from a table in Oracle to SQL Server 2008 R2. I already designed the solution that allows me to move the data and save a copy of the migrated IDs into a stage table. 

Thanks to a Lookup component and the stage table I can ensure to avoid duplicates, since the migration is done in several different moments and the objects migrated do not follow a specific sequencial order.

Below my SSIS schema:

[image]

I use an expression and two variables to gather data from Oracle in slots:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ORDERS   
WHERE OrderID > [@User::Start] AND OrderID <= [@User::End]   
AND STATUS <> 'Open'
```

When all the orders that are not in statsu "Open" have been migrated, we will migrate the remaining delta. To do this I need to lookup to the aready migrated data in Stage. SO the query for the data source will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ORDERS   
WHERE OrderID NOT IN ([@User::AlreadyMigratedIDs])
```

My need would be able to store in variable "AlreadyMigratedIDs" all the IDs present in table Stage.

How would it be possible to use the information in the stage table (on SQL Server) as a condition for the query used in the ADO.net component to gather the source data from Oracle? Can I use any other SSIS, like lookup, before the ADO.net object?

Comment: You need to provide query and the package design in order to  explain your scenario.AFAIK You can use `Execute SQL Task` to store the condition like get all the `ID's` from `SQL Server` and store in a variable .Then create a sql expression with  the above variable (`Select col..from table where ID =@variable`) and use it in `ADO.NET source`

Comment: @paveen: I added the query used to gather the data. I like the idea of storing the IDs in a variable and initialize it with a SQL task. Could you provide an example for this? Which data type should the variable be (in total around 160K records)?

Comment: From where do u get the values for the variables `User::Start` and `User::End` ?

Comment: I enter the values manually since we have to control which record range is moved. Therefore I manually set the range in the variables at Data Flow scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Execute SQL Task before your Data Flow  to store the values of User::Start and User::End from the sql server staging table

```
 Name     Data Type  
 StartID   int
 EndID     int
```

Use ResultSet as `Single Row`

For sample I have taken the query  from Adventure Works 2008 R2

```
Select max([BusinessEntityID]) as StartID
      ,max([DepartmentID]) as EndID
FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]
```

Change the above query to match your needs to get the ID values from your staging table

In the resultset match the results to the variables created

[image]

Now use the 2 variables in your oracle query

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM ORDERS   
 WHERE OrderID > [@User::StartID] AND OrderID <= [@User::EndID]   
 AND STATUS <> 'Open'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question introducing the query I am looking for. My need would be to have all already migrated IDs in a variable. The day we will migrate the remaining delta records, we won't need anymore Start/end variables since we just need to move all the data that has not been migrated yet.

Comment: How are the Id's stored in the variable ?

Comment: That what I am asking. During the migration, I fill Stage table with the order IDs. I liked your suggestion since if I could initialize a variable in a SQL Task, as example, with all the IDs contained in STage Table, then I could use it as indicated in my second query. I am wondering which is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: You need to create an array of all the ID's as a string data type .As per article [Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_using_array_values_in_IN_clause_of_a_select_query.htm)